# how can I bind values to form inputs Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to do an edit page where I fill the input boxes with the values taken from the database.

Say I have a model `Employees` and a field `name`, a form `EmployeeForm` and an input field `name`

```
emp_info = Employees.objects.get(pk=1)
emp_form = EmployeeForm()
```

I am currently doing this and it does not seem to work

```
emp_form.name = emp_info.name
```

template:

```
{{ emp_form.name }}
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can you `raise Exception(emp_info.name + '; ' + emp_form.name)` to see what is being assigned in the view? Do it right after the assignment statement `emp_form.name = emp_info.name` and see what it gets. This could be useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use a model form for some reason, try this

```
emp_info = Employees.objects.get(pk=1)
emp_form = EmployeeForm(initial={'name': emp_info.name})
```

Comment: More about this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)

Answer (score 1):

```
emp_info = Employees.objects.get(pk=1)
```

This will populate your form with the `emp_info`.

```
emp_form = EmployeeForm(instance=emp_info)
```

Comment: I am not using modelforms, so i don't believe this works for me